# CSS three divs in responsive layout (A + B stay, C moves?)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Here's my problem.  I have a Bootstrap v4 card that contains three divs.

A is the most important one and I want it to stay top left.
When the page is wide, I want B and C to be on the right of A.

When the page gets narrow, the card shrinks and C needs to move beneath A.  But there's no reason for B to move at all, I want it to stay in place.

How can I do this please?

[image: Image of what I want to do with three divs]

Comment: Post the code you have attempted.

Answer (score 1):

Do not wrap B & C in a container because this looks like a classical case for floats:

```
<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
<div class="c">C</div>
```

CSS

```
div { 
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.a { width: 400px; height: 400px}
.b { width: 400px; height: 200px}
.c { width: 500px; height: 100px}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/AugustinF/pen/erpvgQ)

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Hey.  You're absolutely right of course.  The tricky thing is all the bits I didn't mention.  The width of A can vary, I want internal elements in B to sub-float, and C needs to be "as wide as it can" to show wrapped content.  This is one of those rabbit-hole questions, sadly.  Your answer is correct in all the fundamentals.  Thanks.